# QFileDialog открытие проводника и выбор файла

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, сигналы-слоты, qfiledialog

При помощи *Qt Designer* создал дизайн. И теперь пытаюсь прописать логику. 
Не могу понять как правильно записать действие по клику. Уже кучу всего перепробовал. Либо вовсе перестает запускаться приложение, либо запускается, но по клику вылетает сразу же.

**main.py**:

```
from checker import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog
import sys

class Cheker(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.show()

        self.btn_download.addAction(self.add_file)


    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def add_file(self):
        action = self.sender()
        if action.btn_download():
            fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self)[0]
            f = open(fname, 'r')
            with f:
                data = f.read()
                self.tableWidget.setItem(data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    check = Cheker()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**checker.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(553, 379)
        MainWindow.setMouseTracking(True)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(217, 217, 217);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.btn_download = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_download.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 10, 111, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.btn_download.setFont(font)
        self.btn_download.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.btn_download.setObjectName("btn_download")
        self.btn_clear = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_clear.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 10, 111, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.btn_clear.setFont(font)
        self.btn_clear.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.btn_clear.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.btn_clear.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.btn_clear.setObjectName("btn_clear")
        self.result_viev = QtWidgets.QListView(self.centralwidget)
        self.result_viev.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 170, 141, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.result_viev.setFont(font)
        self.result_viev.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.result_viev.setObjectName("result_viev")
        self.status_viev = QtWidgets.QListView(self.centralwidget)
        self.status_viev.setEnabled(False)
        self.status_viev.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 250, 141, 41))
        self.status_viev.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.status_viev.setObjectName("status_viev")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 140, 111, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 220, 111, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(75)
        font.setStrikeOut(False)
        font.setKerning(True)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 60, 101, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setUnderline(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("border-color: rgb(188, 0, 0);\n"
"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 361, 311))
        self.tableWidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(244, 244, 244);")
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(0)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.setTabOrder(self.btn_download, self.btn_clear)
        MainWindow.setTabOrder(self.btn_clear, self.result_viev)
        MainWindow.setTabOrder(self.result_viev, self.status_viev)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "FB - чекер "))
        self.btn_download.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Загрузить"))
        self.btn_clear.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Очистить"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Код с почты"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Статус"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "СТАРТ"))
```

Буду признателен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кнопка излучает сигнал [**clicked()**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked), когда она активируется мышью,
пробелом или сочетанием клавиш. 
Подключитесь к этому сигналу, чтобы выполнить действие кнопки.

[**Сигналы и слоты**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) используются для связи между объектами.
Механизм сигналов и слотов является центральной особенностью *Qt* и, вероятно,
той частью, которая больше всего отличается от функций,
предоставляемых другими фреймворками.

Я не знаю для чего вы решили использовать виджет `QTableWidget`
и что вы туда решили записывать,
поэтому я заменил его на виджет [**QTextEdit**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html).

Я улучшил написание статической функции [**getOpenFileName()**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getOpenFileName)

**q1411810.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog
from checker import Ui_MainWindow

        
class Cheker(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.show()
        
# ???        self.btn_download.addAction(self.add_file)
        self.btn_download.clicked.connect(self.add_file)                  # !!! +++
        
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def add_file(self):
# ???        action = self.sender()
# ???        if action.btn_download():

        fname, filetype = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self, 
            "Open file",
            ".", 
            "Python Files (*.py);;Text Files(*.txt)"
        )
        if fname:
#            f = open(fname, 'r')
#            with f:
            with open(fname, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                data = f.read()
# ???                self.tableWidget.setItem(data)
                self.textEdit.setText(data)
     
      
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    check = Cheker()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**checker.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(553, 379)
        MainWindow.setMouseTracking(True)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(217, 217, 217);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.btn_download = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_download.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 10, 111, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.btn_download.setFont(font)
        self.btn_download.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.btn_download.setObjectName("btn_download")
        self.btn_clear = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_clear.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 10, 111, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.btn_clear.setFont(font)
        self.btn_clear.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.btn_clear.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.btn_clear.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.btn_clear.setObjectName("btn_clear")
        self.result_viev = QtWidgets.QListView(self.centralwidget)
        self.result_viev.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 170, 141, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.result_viev.setFont(font)
        self.result_viev.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.result_viev.setObjectName("result_viev")
        self.status_viev = QtWidgets.QListView(self.centralwidget)
        self.status_viev.setEnabled(False)
        self.status_viev.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 250, 141, 41))
        self.status_viev.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.status_viev.setObjectName("status_viev")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 140, 111, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 220, 111, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(75)
        font.setStrikeOut(False)
        font.setKerning(True)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 60, 101, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setUnderline(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("border-color: rgb(188, 0, 0);\n"
"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        
        '''
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 361, 311))
        self.tableWidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(244, 244, 244);")
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(0)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        '''
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 361, 311))
        self.textEdit.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(244, 244, 244);")
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")        
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.setTabOrder(self.btn_download, self.btn_clear)
        MainWindow.setTabOrder(self.btn_clear, self.result_viev)
        MainWindow.setTabOrder(self.result_viev, self.status_viev)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "FB - чекер "))
        self.btn_download.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Загрузить"))
        self.btn_clear.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Очистить"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Код с почты"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Статус"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "СТАРТ"))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ` self.btn_download.clicked.connect(self.add_file) ` - так я когда пробовал разные варианты, пробовал этот метод, тоже была ошибка. Видать ошибка все же в функции была и использовании QTableWidget. Но делал все по мануалам которые в иннете нашел.    "Я не знаю для чего вы решили использовать виджет QTableWidget и что вы туда решили записывать,
поэтому я заменил его на виджет QTextEdit." - я хотел туда передавать список почт, который в свою очередь по клику будет передаваться в переменную, для поиска письма по протоколу IMAP.

Comment: @Юра, нет, привязка сигнала к слоту в событии кнопки никак не связано с виджетом QTableWidget. Я ответил на вопрос: QFileDialog открытие проводника и выбор файла ? Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour . Если у вас есть другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос.